# How do I extract results with special conditions using restAssured?

Tags: java, rest-assured, rest

I have a List returned as response. I need to get The name of a person with less than starts 5

```
{
   "person": {
    "list": [
        {
          "id":A135443
          "name":"Jeff"
          "start":5
        },
        {
          "id":A135410
          "name":"JohnDoe"
          "start":5
        },
        {
          "id":A135418
          "name":"Adam"
          "start":4
        },
        {
          "id":A135431
          "name":"Harry"
          "start":3
        },
         ....
   ]}}
```

In the above code, "Adam" and "Harry" with less than 5 start shall be stored in the array.

How can i store results that meet certain conditions in an array?

Comment: Easiest option is probably to just extract the whole list, then filter or pick the element(s) after that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a lot of ways you can do this, here are a couple of examples which are very much self explanatory - let me know otherwise and I'll be happy to explain

**Option 1 :**

```
Response res = RestAssured.given().when().get("http://localhost:8080/trial/1");
JsonPath js = res.jsonPath();
List<Object> values = js.getList("person.list.findAll { it.start < 5 }.name");
```

**Option 2 :**

```
List<Object> values1 = RestAssured.given().when().get("http://soapractice.mocklab.io/thing/4").then().extract()
.body().jsonPath().getList("person.list.findAll { it.start < 5 }.name");
```

**Option 3 :**

```
String def = RestAssured.given().when().get("http://soapractice.mocklab.io/thing/4").then().extract().body().asString();
JsonPath js1 = new JsonPath(def);
List<Object> values2 = js1.getList("person.list.findAll { it.start < 5 }.name");
```

The official documentation is very useful - [Link](https://github.com/rest-assured/rest-assured/wiki/Usage#example-1)

Comment: IMO, Save to `List<String>`  var for future use is better than `List<Object>`

Comment: It works perfectly! You're god of RestAssured

Comment: @lucasnguyen17 I prefer to leave the choice of the data type to the OP, This is more of a generic answer

Comment: `{
   "person": {
    "list": [
        {
          "id":A135443
          "name":"Jeff"
          "start":5
        },
        {
          "id":A135410
          "name":"JohnDoe"
          "start":5
        },
        {
          "id":A135418
          "name":"Adam"
          "start":4
        },
        {
          "id":A135431
          "name":"Harry"
          "start":3
        },
         ....
   ], 
  "cnt": 10
}}`

I tried the way you explained it to me. I've got the person.list.name data
but i can't got person.cnt data.. What am I supposed to do?

Comment: @Holland kindly edit the same question or raise a new question, hard to follow the requirement from comments

Comment: out of list bracket, there is cnt data(at comment last line).
so i use Option2 like this
`List<Object> values1 = RestAssured.given().when().get("http://soapractice.mocklab.io/thing/4").then().extract()
.body().jsonPath().getList("person.cnt");`
but stored value is null. and i try List<Integer> and getint function, failed to stored in values1 :(

Comment: I still don't get it, kindly edit the question

Comment: @Holland `cnt` is not in an array, you don't use `getList`, just use `getInt("person.cnt")`